# How to stop video on Android after calling ddmlib's startScreenRecorder method?

Tags: android, video, record, ddms

I am using ddmlib of Android and there is this method (1). By that I can, obviously, start to record some video.

The question is, how do I stop the video from recording? There is not equivalent stop method.

Thanks!

(1) http://javadox.com/com.android.tools.ddms/ddmlib/23.0.1/com/android/ddmlib/IDevice.html#startScreenRecorder(java.lang.String,com.android.ddmlib.ScreenRecorderOptions,com.android.ddmlib.IShellOutputReceiver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I can stop it by IShellOutputReceiver. When I want to stop it, its "isCancelled()" method has to return true.